# Generating REST MVC5 API documentation using WebApi.HelpPage

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I have an API which I need to produce documentation for. I've used the following article to setup the documentation on my API and it's working pretty well.

I'm using the: `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage` NuGet package to generate documentation for my WebApi and I've been following this tutorial.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-api-help-pages

All is working well and I've got some excellent documentation for my Api Endpoints. Sadly the data objects it's returning have no associated documentation and I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to do this. In the past I've used Sandcastle etc and it's combined the documentation files.

So currently as documented I've uncommented the line:

```
config.SetDocumentationProvider(new XmlDocumentationProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/XmlDocument.xml")));
```

This has allowed documentation for the api assembly to be generated but I can't find a way of referencing additional assemblies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By `I can't find a way of referencing additional assemblies.` if you are referring to generating help documentation from models present in other assemblies, then you can take a look at the following response:

[How can Xml Documentation for Web Api include documentation from beyond the main project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895257/how-can-xml-documentation-for-web-api-include-documentation-from-beyond-the-main)

Comment: This is great. Thanks, bit embarrased I didn't notice this. The answer is great, I changed the constructor to accept an array of strings. Added a comment on the original answer.