# Web API help pages - use XML comments from other projects and base classes

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

I added [Help Pages](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages) to my Web API project. However most of the documentation does not show on the help pages because:

1. the objects used as parameter types and return types are *defined in a separate assembly/project*, and
2. documentation for the controllers' actions are *defined in separate interfaces* implemented by the controllers. Also, these interfaces are in a separate assembly/project.

An overview of my solution structure:

- Web API project
- Class library with data objects (used as parameter types and return types in controller actions)
- Class library with controller interfaces (implemented by each controller)

Is it possible for Help Pages to a) incorporate XML documentation from separate projects, and b) apply the XML documentation from an interface to the class that implements it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this as follows:

1. To handle XML files from multiple projects I've incorporated the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23473072/65775). This code essentially does what @lcryder suggested but automatically.
2. To apply XML documentation from an interface to its implemented class I am using GhostDoc's Document This option to copy the XML documentation.

However I'm not happy with #2 because it requires manual intervention and I have to remember to recopy the XML documentation whenever it changes, so I'm still looking for a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the other projects .xml files (in the /bin folder) copy the member collection and paste into your .xml file.

Comment: This works (contrary to my previous comment) but I'd prefer something that doesn't require manual intervention. I've been looking at [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22165724/web-api-help-page-xml-comments-from-more-than-1-files) and they help with the 'separate projects' part of my question, but I still would like to figure out the 'interface' part of my question.