# Documenting descriptions on Complex Types

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-helppages

Within my API I'm trying to document the different field descriptions, however none of attributes seem to work. I know this functionality is supposed to have been recently implemented within WebAPI 5.1 (running WebAPI.HelpPage 5.1.2).

[ASP.Net Web API Help Pages: Document Model Data Annotations - Work Item 877](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/877)

I'm trying to document both my response model:

[image: Response Model]

And the individual fields/properties

[image: Property description]

I've tried a mixture of XML comments, DataMember and Display attributes but none seem to be picked up.

```
/// <summary>
/// blah blah blah
/// </summary>
[DataContract(Name = "Application")]
public class Application
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Please Display!
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    [Display(Description="Please Display!")]
    [StringLength(11, MinimumLength = 11)]
    public string ApplicationId { get; set; }
```

Here is a sample from my Areas/HelpPage/App_Start/HelpPageConfig.cs

```
namespace WebAPI.Areas.HelpPage
{
    #pragma warning disable 1591
    /// <summary>
    /// Use this class to customize the Help Page.
    /// For example you can set a custom <see cref="System.Web.Http.Description.IDocumentationProvider"/> to supply the documentation
    /// or you can provide the samples for the requests/responses.
    /// </summary>
    public static class HelpPageConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // remove unwanted formatters
            config.Formatters.Clear();
            var jsonsettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None };
            config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
            config.Formatters.Add(new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
            config.SetDocumentationProvider(new XmlDocumentationProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/bin/WebAPI.XML")));
            // create sample objects
            config.SetSampleObjects(new Dictionary<Type, object>
            {
                { typeof(MyResponse), new MyResponse() { 
                    Message = "Key d795677d-6477-494f-80c5-874b318cc020 is not recognised", 
                    Code = ResponseCode.InvalidKey, Id = null }
                }
            });             
            //*** More Sample Requests ***
        }
    }
    #pragma warning restore 1591
}
```

**Update 10/06/2014**: My class definitions are stored in a separate library. I've noticed a discrepancy here. The main API and class definition library were generating separate XML files.

**API Project**

[image: API Project Build Output]

**Definition Project**

[image: Model Definition Build Output]

I've attempted to rectify this by making the Definition write to the same XML project. However this doesn't work, and the class definition entries aren't added.

Comment: Can you share how your `Areas\HelpPage\HelpPageConfig.cs` looks like?

Comment: I've added a snippet of my HelpPageConfig.cs

Comment: Thanks...i would first check if the file `WebAPI.XML` indeed has the xml comments that you decorated the properties..we by defualt do not support the text present in `Display` attribute...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can Xml Documentation for Web Api include documentation from beyond the main project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895257/how-can-xml-documentation-for-web-api-include-documentation-from-beyond-the-main)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have a content displayed in Description section you need to feel  section of XML comments. If you would have your model class placed inside your webapi project - then this would be a solution. Your problem is that you need to read xml documentation form 2 xml files and one time and XmlDocumentationProvider does not support that. My suggestion is to create your own MultipleFilesXmlDocumentationProvider with a little effort like this:

```
public class MultipleFilesXmlDocumentationProvider : IDocumentationProvider
{
    IEnumerable<XmlDocumentationProvider> xmlDocumentationProviders;

    public MultipleFilesXmlDocumentationProvider(IEnumerable<string> documentPaths)
    {
        xmlDocumentationProviders = documentPaths.Select(path => new XmlDocumentationProvider(path));
    }

    public string GetDocumentation(HttpParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor)
    {
        foreach(XmlDocumentationProvider provider in xmlDocumentationProviders)
        {
            string documentation = provider.GetDocumentation(parameterDescriptor);
            if(documentation != null)
                return documentation;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public string GetDocumentation(HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        foreach (XmlDocumentationProvider provider in xmlDocumentationProviders)
        {
            string documentation = provider.GetDocumentation(actionDescriptor);
            if (documentation != null)
                return documentation;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public string GetDocumentation(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
    {
        foreach (XmlDocumentationProvider provider in xmlDocumentationProviders)
        {
            string documentation = provider.GetDocumentation(controllerDescriptor);
            if (documentation != null)
                return documentation;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public string GetResponseDocumentation(HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        foreach (XmlDocumentationProvider provider in xmlDocumentationProviders)
        {
            string documentation = provider.GetDocumentation(actionDescriptor);
            if (documentation != null)
                return documentation;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This will be just wrapper over XmlDocumentationProvider - it will work with a collection of XmlDocumentationProvider and looks for the first one that will provide desired documentation. Then you change your configuration in HelpPageConfig to use your MultipleFilesXmlDocumentationProvider:

```
config.SetDocumentationProvider(
    new MultipleFilesXmlDocumentationProvider(
        new string[] { 
            HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/bin/WebAPI.XML"), 
            HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/bin/EntityModel.Definitions.XML")
        }
    )
 );
```

Of course take into account that for the configuration above both XML files should be within WebAPI project bin folder.

Comment: Just a note, this may possibly be due to a newer ASP.net but I also had to inherit from: IModelDocumentationProvider and implement: GetDocumentation(Type type) and GetDocumentation(MemberInfo member)