# Web Api 2 help documentation generator

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-apiexplorer

I have installed Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage to my web api 2 project and can successfully output the /help pages.

One thing i cant seem to get going however is getting it to generate the xml comment documentation i have added to classes that are referenced in a separate project.  So for instance my web api controller comments all appear fine.
However in project x that is referenced in the web api project i have classes that have XML documentation applied but none of these appear in the /help files.

I know i can set the web api xml document file to be referenced in HelpPageConfig.cs

```
config.SetDocumentationProvider(new XmlDocumentationProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/XmlDocument.xml")));
```

How can i get the generator to pick up XML files from other referenced projects as well or this is a current limitation of the api explorer tool?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate [How can Xml Documentation for Web Api include documentation from beyond the main project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895257/how-can-xml-documentation-for-web-api-include-documentation-from-beyond-the-main)