# Asp.NET Web API : Help Description not generated for classes in referenced project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I am able to setup Web API Help and it does generate the Help page. However, the response and request class types which have properties of types that are defined in different project do not get documented.

This is the sample code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Add New Product
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="productRequest">The new Product Request to be added</param>
    /// <returns>Operation status and information of the new product request</returns>
    // POST api/InventorySystem/Products
    [Route("")]
    [HttpPost]
    public InsertProductResponse Post([FromBody]InsertProductRequest productRequest)
    {
        InsertProductResponse response = null;

        // Some code goes here
        response = new InsertProductResponse ();

        return response;
    }
```

The Help page does contain description "Add New Product". However when drilling down into "InsertProductResponse" object there is no description.

InsertProductResponse is defined in a separate class library and XML document is defined for this class. But it is not seen on Help page.

I am thinking that the XML documentation generated by the class library is not merged with the XML documentation generated by Web API project (App_Data/XmlDocument.xml). How do I get this to work?

Comment: It seems that this error might have been caused by your [Route("")] attribute being empty. Have you tried removing this attribute and just using the default route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it - Some code in Help Area needs to be changed. Refer this post

[How can Xml Documentation for Web Api include documentation from beyond the main project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895257/how-can-xml-documentation-for-web-api-include-documentation-from-beyond-the-main)