# Specify example requests for swagger's "Try it out"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Is there a way to specify example requests for swagger? Maybe even multiple ones?

The `Try it out` button shows only generic values like:

```
{
    "firstName": "string",
    "lastName": "string"
}
```

for

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

It becomes very difficult to use with large objects when you have to edit all the values first. I know I could use Postman, and I do too, but being able to create **multiple** good looking and useful examples with swagger would be very nice.

Comment: @ArtemIgnatovich nope, this isn't it. I'm lookig for example/test values and possible for  multiple requests for trying out the API. Setting default values is _easy_ and they are not the same thing.

Comment: I haven't heard of this feature before. @t3chb0t now it is clear what you've meant.
You can render a section (using plain html) with examples with formatted data (to copy and paste it into the try it out window), but I dont think it is possible in "try it out" section.

Comment: One more option to try is to investigate a built-in plugin system for swagger-ui or already existing public extensions (there is also a room for writing your own and get some stars at github he-he).

Comment: @ArtemIgnatovich I think I've found it, see _Request Body Examples_ [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/)

Comment: Good to know! There is always a room for learning something new even if you are 99% sure that this does not exist.

Comment: Do you use Swashbuckle or Swagger-Net? They probably provide annotations to customize property examples.

Comment: @Helen this would mean only a single example; see the link in my previous comment, it's possible with extra configs

Comment: See if this helps: https://github.com/mattfrear/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters#how-to-use---request-examples

Comment: @Helen cool, this is pretty interesting ;-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In .Net5 you can add a SchemaFilter to Swagger in the Startup.cs

```
public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SchemaFilter<ExampleSchemaFilter>();
    });
}
```

In the ExampleSchemaFilter.cs you simply define an OpenApiObject for your specific class:

```
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Any;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;

public class ExampleSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.Type == typeof(User))
        {
            schema.Example = new OpenApiObject()
            {
                ["firstName"] = new OpenApiString("John"),
                ["lastName"] = new OpenApiString("Doe"),
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how `ExampleSchemaFilter` would be used in code?

Comment: My answer is the example how to use the ExampleSchemaFilter in code.
In .AddSwaggerGen() you register the ExampleSchemaFilter and in this case Swagger automatically sets the values in the Try it out with the values you gave the object in the SchemaFilter.

Comment: My bad -- I thought it needed to be applied as an attribute.  Thank you!

Answer (score 19):

With ASP.NET Core 3.1, Swagger OAS 3 and Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.4.1, the following model class + XML comments works for me:-

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// A user.
    /// </summary>
    public class User
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The user's first name.
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>Jane</example>
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The user's last name.
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>Austin</example>
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

Now when I click "Try it Out" (for a POST operation that takes a `User` model in the message body), I get the defaults:-

```
{
    "firstName": "Jane",
    "lastName": "Austin"
}
```

Comment: I currently cannot try it out but does it mean that Swagger can read the `example` element of the comment?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's Swagger or Swashbuckle doing the work here (or maybe they both are), but basically yes: it's reading the `<example>` XML comment and using that value as the default value when doing "Try it out".

Comment: @AndrewWebb I have posted the question yesterday with the same requirement, my question has been linked here and I got your answer. I have tried doing the same, provided all the relevant technologies are same as mentioned in my application. Is there any configuration needed or can you share further what else required to see this.

Comment: @Monibrata if the types are in a different project, make sure you are outputting XML documentation for that project, and add the file to IncludeXmlComments in the SwaggerGenOptions see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50837958/914352

Answer (score 3):

This is how I do it (using .Net Core 7.0, would probably work for older version):

**Controller declaration (example):**

```
        [HttpGet("DynValuesCycleGensetPerMicrogridAndDate")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<DynamicValuesByMicrogridDto>> DynValuesCycleGensetPerMicrogridAndDate(
            [SwaggerTryItOutDefaulValue("1")] int microgridId,
            [SwaggerTryItOutDefaulValue("2023-10-07 15:00")] DateTimeOffset dateTimeStart,
            [SwaggerTryItOutDefaulValue("2023-10-09 15:00")] DateTimeOffset dateTimeEnd)
        {
            //...
```

**Program initialisation:**

```
  builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
    {
        options.SchemaFilter<SwaggerTryItOutDefaulValue>();
        //...
```

**ISchemaFilter:**

```
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;
using System.Reflection;

namespace GeneralAsp
{
    public class SwaggerTryItOutDefaultValue : ISchemaFilter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Apply is called for each parameter
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="schema"></param>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
        {
            if (context.ParameterInfo != null)
            {
                var att = context.ParameterInfo.GetCustomAttribute<SwaggerTryItOutDefaultValueAttribute>();
                if (att != null)
                {
                    schema.Example = new Microsoft.OpenApi.Any.OpenApiString(att.Value.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Attribute:**

```
namespace GeneralAsp
{
    public class SwaggerTryItOutDefaultValueAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string Value { get; }

        public SwaggerTryItOutDefaultValueAttribute(string value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would be the code when you have an object within a post-request and you want to set the default values for the properties?