# Change the example value of Swagger using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger

I have an ASP.NET program that uses Swagger to provide API docs. Current;y we have one endpoint that takes a Date value like below:

```
{
  "region": "string",
  "date": "2023-07-27T13:07:05.359Z"
}
```

and its corresponding class is defined as:

```
{
  [Serializable]
  public class Msg
  {
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
  }
```

The problem is, `Msg` is defined in a separate library and we cant directly change any or it. But we want to revise the Json examle value to:

```
{
  "region": "string",
  "date": "2023-07-27"
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61955594/396005

Comment: @BronDavies sorry the question was a bit misleading. We can't change the definition at all--it is defined in a DLL file. But the first answer in your link seems worth trying tho. Will give a try can come back

Answer (score 0):

If your model would be in the same project then there would be some more elegant ways to solve this issue with annotations. But in your case you can register a custom schema filter and define an OpenApiObject linked to your **Msg** class from your library.

```
public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SchemaFilter<ExampleSchemaFilter>();
    });
}
```

In the ExampleSchemaFilter.cs you simply define an OpenApiObject for your **Msg** class:

```
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Any;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;

public class ExampleSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.Type == typeof(Msg))
        {
            schema.Example = new OpenApiObject()
            {
                ["region"] = new OpenApiString("string"),
                ["date"] = new OpenApiString("2023-07-27"),
            };
        }
    }
}
```