# Self documenting asp.net api

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, api, self-documenting-code

I created an Asp.net api in VS2015. Inside the Areas>HelpPage>App_Start>HelpPageConfig.cs I uncommented line 37

```
config.SetDocumentationProvider(new XmlDocumentationProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/XmlDocument.xml")));
```

There was no XmlDocument.xml in the App_Data folder for the project so I created one with the tags I'd seen in self documenting xml's in other apis

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<doc>
  <assembly>
    <name>NameOfApiHere</name>
  </assembly>
  <members>
  </members>
</doc>
```

but when building and/or running the application nothing is going into the xml. It's my understanding that when this is turned on the XML sel documents based on each ///summary for a given method with an intellisense alert for any public method that does not have a summary but I cna't find any code that would explicitly copy summary information to this xml as "member" tags inside of teh "members" tag nor is it happening. What step am I missing that I'm not seeing in the how to's on the internet for turning on self documentation in an APi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In project propeties repoint XML documentation destintion folder to your desired folder. I suppose it would be better to use `app_data` instead of `App_code` folder.

take a look into 1st and 2nd steps of [this question answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895257/how-can-xml-documentation-for-web-api-include-documentation-from-beyond-the-main)

Comment: This led me to it, it was in the properties unter build, I had to both check "XML Documentation file:" and set the path to my xml

Comment: did you tried change folder to `app_data`? In any case `XmlDocumentationProvider` is in your project Debug it and you'll see why it's not working

Comment: yes, it is in App_data, the App_Code was a typo in the question that I will correct

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the `XmlDocument.xml` file that you added (I think this autogenerates) and specify the path to it in the project settings -> Build tab inside the **Output** section.